# How to get Microsoft Graph API token to read mails

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, postman

I'm trying to retrieve mails from my organization's mailbox, and I can do that via Graph Explorer. However, when I use the same information that I used in Graph Explorer, the generated token returns an error stating '/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.' in me/messages endpoint.

So, how can I generate the acceptable token for the /me endpoint?

An example python code or example Postman request would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the endpoint you're using in **Graph Explorer** is something like this

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages`

`/me` is referring to the user signed into **Graph Explorer**. If you want to read another user's messages you would use

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@domain.com/messages`

When connecting to **Graph API** as an application with no user interaction, you can never use `/me` endpoints, as there's no user logged in.

**Reference**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0

**Python example to list messages**

```
import requests

def get_messages(access_token, user):

    request_url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user}/messages"

    request_headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
    }

    result = requests.get(url = request_url, headers = request_headers)
    
    return(result)

msgs = get_messages(access_token = token['access_token'], user = "userPrincipalName@domain.com")

print(msgs.content)
```

**Additional example of obtaining a token, using an app registration and client secret**

```
import msal

def get_token_with_client_secret(client_id, client_secret, tenant_id):
    # This function is to obtain a bearer token using the client credentials flow, with a client secret instead of a certificate
    # https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider
    
    app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        client_id         = client_id,
        client_credential = client_secret,
        authority         = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}")

    scopes = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]

    token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes = scopes)

    return(token)
```

Comment: Hey, Scott! Thanks for the answer. I was so focused on the Graph Explorer that I couldn't realize that 'me' endpoint is causing the issue. Thanks for pointing out. Right now I can fetch mails and I'm continuing my work :D.